# Django REST Framework: allow any user can edit any data (remove object_permission)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-permissions, django-rest-viewsets

I am using Django REST Framework's `viewsets.ModelViewSet` to list, create, update and delete table rows. For the following `Tasks` model it works fine.

But it only allows to list, create, update and delete of own entries (i.e. resource owner) or the user should be superuser. I want to make this API that other users can view, modify and delete regardless of the creator. In simple words, all authenticated users can view/edit anyone's entries. Is there any way to do this?

views.py

```
class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Tasks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
    'DATE_FORMAT': "%m/%d/%Y",
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 50,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app_utils.utils.custom_exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
}
```

Comment: DRF certainly does not enforce that by default. The only permission class you have here is IsAuthenticated, so there are no object level permissions being enforced at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if I haven't added "permission_classes" to the viewset, then what will happen?

Comment: It won't even insist on the user being authenticated - any request will be permitted from anyone.